# wget internal buffer size

Tags: wget, io, curl

I'm constantly using `wget` to download many files over 1GB each. I'm getting concerned about how this may be straining my HDD. Can `wget`'s internal buffer size be modified so that it writes to my HDD less often? What about `curl`?

Comment: In what sense is it going to be "straining your HDD" -- do you want this stuff saved on disk, or not?

Comment: @goldilocks I would rather have it write to disk every 1 MB rather than every 1 KB for example. That way it will only write to HDD 1 time rather than about 1000 times.

Comment: As long as you have free memory, writes are buffered by the OS disk cache anyway (watch it grow when you do this).  I won't say there's anything wrong with what you want to do, but I doubt it is going to make any ultimate difference to the disk's lifespan.

Comment: Yeah, you would probably only do this to keep it from swamping the queue but there are block-level controls for that sort of behavior. The requests are going to be merged by the scheduler anyways.

Comment: Also, hard disks have their own buffer which is at least a few MB: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer I'm sure there are more than a few engineers that have given some thought to this issue already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an external bufffer, and pipe the output through it.

For example, the program [`buffer`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/buffer.1.html) allows you to buffer up to 1GB, and you can specify at which fill level percentage it should start to write :

To buffer 10 blocks of 512 kB (5MB) and write out to the file when the buffer is filled to 85%:

`wget example.com -O- | buffer -s 512k -b 10 -p 85 > ./outfile.txt`

(may need `apt-get install buffer`)

---

But, other than directly answering the question, this does not look like something you should need to do manually. Maybe you can configure your file system to cache write operations a little longer before actually writing to the disk? Depends on what problem you want to solve exactly.

Comment: +1 I'm guessing `buffer` is so obscure because it mostly replicates `dd`, only with the added `-m`, `-p`, and `-b` features that make what you are suggesting possible.  Unfortunately I can't find the upstream source; while it's in debian it's not in e.g. fedora.