# Horrible wget download speed to CIFS mount; local download and cp to share is fine

Tags: linux, wget, cifs

I'm having a horrible wget download speed to a CIFS share.

This is the speed of wget download directly to the share:

```
d64-18ef-43d5-b295-   2%[                    ] 100.18M  11.7MB/s    eta 6m 2s
```

This is the speed wget download to local FS:

```
glish_x32.iso?t=cff   6%[>                   ] 253.20M  55.2MB/s    eta 70s
```

Surprisingly, this is the copy speed from local FS to the CIFS share:

```
root@gw:/tmp# pv Win10_22H2_English_x32.iso > /opt/isos_rw/Win10_22H2_English_x32.iso
1.29GiB 0:00:25 [53.4MiB/s] [==============>                   ] 45% ETA 0:00:30
```

So obviously wget is doing something funny here. How to fix this? Other download tools are also an option.

**EDIT**:
My active mount:

```
//172.16.8.232/Install/Isos on /opt/isos_rw type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,cache=strict,username=InstallRW,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=172.16.8.232,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=8388608,wsize=8388608,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

The machine in question is my gateway machine, 4-core AMD GX-412TC SOC with 2GB of RAM. My uplink is 0.5 Gig fiber, connection to CIFS share is via CAT6e 1000BASE-T copper.

On gateway, both interfaces are full duplex:

```
[   13.385878] igb 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: igb: enp1s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[   14.325858] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: igb: enp2s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
```

Hardware:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
        Memory at f7b00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        I/O ports at 1000 [size=32]
        Memory at f7b20000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=5 Masked-
        Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-0d-b9-ff-ff-57-9b-8c
        Capabilities: [1a0] Transaction Processing Hints
        Kernel driver in use: igb
        Kernel modules: igb
```

CIFS server (on my LAN) shows

```
Intel I210 Gigabit Network Connection 1 Gbps
```

Comment below what else is worth adding.

**EDIT N**:
I'm going to order new hardware to check if this is a hardware issue. I will report back.

**EDIT N+1**:
Run wget and top. See the resuls. CPU utilization is some 33% to CIFS, while to SSD it is almost full, 95%.

[image: CIFS wget CPU utilization]

[image: SSD wget CPU utilization]

**EDIT N+2**:
Got new hardware today. It has also I210 NICS instead of I211. Now I should have douple the amount of transmit-receive-queues. I'm setting up the hardware now.

**EDIT N+3**:
New hardware makes no difference. However, I was doing some stracing.

```
wget to SSD (55 MB/s):

_newselect(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949999}) = 1 (in [4], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949994})
read(4, "\7\0\0H\213D$0L\213 H\270\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0H\2138H\270\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
write(3, "\7\0\0H\213D$0L\213 H\270\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0H\2138H\270\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
write(3, "_net_resolve_address\0grub_net_ro"..., 4096) = 4096
_newselect(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949999}) = 1 (in [4], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949995})
read(4, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
write(3, "\0\0\1\0\0\0\3\0\0\0Y\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\236\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\f\0"..., 4096) = 4096
_newselect(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949999}) = 1 (in [4], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949995})
read(4, "\0\0\225\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\240\0\0\0\20\0"..., 8192) = 8192
write(3, "\0\0\225\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\240\0\0\0\20\0"..., 4096^C) = 4096
strace: Process 12012 detached

wget to CIFS (13MB/s):

_newselect(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949999}) = 1 (in [4], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949994})
read(4, "ATH\213L$0H\213T$8H\213t$(L\215L$pH\270\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
write(3, "ATH\213L$0H\213T$8H\213t$(L\215L$pH\270\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
_newselect(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949999}) = 1 (in [4], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949994})
read(4, "\0\0\0\0\0D\2138\351\202\6\0\0\200{\1\0\17\205d\4\0\0A\376\305\17\205[\4\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
write(3, "\0\0\0\0\0D\2138\351\202\6\0\0\200{\1\0\17\205d\4\0\0A\376\305\17\205[\4\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
_newselect(5, [4], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949999}) = 1 (in [4], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=949994})
read(4, "CRIPTION\0net_get_dhcp_option\0per"..., 8192) = 8192
write(3, "CRIPTION\0net_get_dhcp_option\0per"..., 8192^Cstrace: Process 12050 detached
 <detached ...>
```

So, cp ends up using quite the optimal write(2) buffer size of 131072. However, wget uses 8192. This buffer size clearly changes according to context, as you can see that direct wget to FS uses write buffer size of 4096.

If I buffer the output by myself:

```
root@gw:/opt/isos_rw/ubuntu# wget http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/Linux/mirrors/debian-cdimage/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.7.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso -O - | dd bs=100k > iso.iso
--2023-04-23 16:18:45--  http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/Linux/mirrors/debian-cdimage/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.7.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso
Resolving ftp.funet.fi (ftp.funet.fi)... 193.166.3.2, 2001:708:10:8::2
Connecting to ftp.funet.fi (ftp.funet.fi)|193.166.3.2|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 672137216 (641M) [application/x-iso9660-image]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                           100%[===========================================>] 641.00M  43.2MB/s    in 14s

2023-04-23 16:18:59 (46.0 MB/s) - written to stdout [672137216/672137216]

1+9203 records in
1+9203 records out
672137216 bytes (672 MB, 641 MiB) copied, 13.9526 s, 48.2 MB/s
```

I reach good enough speeds. Any clues?

Forgot to add kernel version earlier, here it is:

```
root@gw:/opt/isos_rw/ubuntu# uname -a
Linux gw 4.19.0-23-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.19.269-1 (2022-12-20) i686 GNU/Linux
```

BTW, curl has the same speed:

```
root@gw:/opt/isos_rw/ubuntu# curl http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/Linux/mirrors/debian-cdimage/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.7.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso -o iso.iso
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  641M  100  641M    0     0  12.3M      0  0:00:51  0:00:51 --:--:-- 12.7M
```

With strace analysis, curl alternates between 4096 and 12288 byte writes to SSD and curiously does 8192 byte writes to CIFS, seemingly also utilizing some kind of context to get this value. curl splits its 102400 byte recv buffer into multiple 8192 buffer writes on CIFS.

Comment: Two flows competing for bandwidth at the same time?

Comment: yeah, how are you connected to the CIFS share?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Give `curl` or `aria2c` a try though I'm 99% sure wget is **not** the culprit, there's something else going on.

Comment: I've just checked wget's source code and it has nothing peculiar which could have resulted in reduced download speeds.

Comment: Thank you for input. I'll try to verify later if netcat -transferred file gives me the same performance issues. If it does.. well I'd be even more dumbfounded then. Jus shooting in the dark here; could this be transmit queue issue? My I211 NIC has (only?) 2 transmit/receive queues.

Comment: Same problem here. I also try to use axel as download program and has very poor results. I suspected I use axel with too many threads (-n 8 option) but with wget or axel -n 1 , it remains slow. I also have fast transfert rate from wget to ssd and from ssd to cif mount. I think this can be related to how these programs write on disk. Maybe they write bytes 1 by 1 and flush between each which can trigger unefficient network calls. I have to play around with these program and test to write my own download program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have this issue on my setup.

As Artem S.Tashkinov suggested, I tried to use **curl** instead of wget and magic happened : I write to my cif fs at full speed. ✅

So **wget** and **axel** might have write  methods on fs like maybe flush between each byte write so it generate inefficient network calls roundtrips (This is speculation).

edit:

I did some quick search after this post, and I found [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149521/wget-internal-buffer-size)

It explains how to add a buffer system to wget. The command I used is

`wget https://abigfile.iso -O- | buffer -s 512k -b 10 -p 85 > ./outfile.iso`

This command let me also download with my full bandwitdth.

I suspect now axel and wget has default small buffers with **no (as of 08/23)** exposed options to let user change this.

Comment: This is exactly the same conclusion I arrived to in the end. Putting arbitrary buffer in the middle fixed the issue.